# Why HTTP POST request does not work from the embedded app, but works if sent from the curl?

Tags: http, curl, post, network-programming, ip-camera

I am trying to debug the following bug.

There is a Linux embedded application (which acts like an HTTP client). It sends HTTP GET and POST requests to an IP camera (which acts like an HTTP server). GET requests handled successfully, and the client gets the response. But POST request to the same parameter causes the server not to response at all, and HTTP client aborts the connection after 10 sec timeout.

Note: when I send the same HTTP POST request from the `curl` on the embedded device - it works! `curl` gets the OK response.

In the Wireshark I compared both HTTP POST packets and saw, that they were identical with regard to the HTTP fields! (Content-Length, Content-Type, HOST, IP, etc... are equal, only the User-Agent differs, what makes sense).

The only difference between the packets is, that the HTTP POST packet which is sent from the embedded app is divided to 2 TCP frames, while the curl HTTP POST packet always fits only in 1 TCP frame.

Also note, that we have another camera model from the same vendor which handles successfully POST requests from the embedded APP! So I believe that the HTTP POST requests is correct...

I could say that the problematic camera has a bug, but WHY IT WORKS CONSISTENTLY WITH CURL?

I really don't understand WTF.... Do you have any idea how to debug / how to fix?

I thought about some ugly work-around (because of the close release hhh): I could delegate the HTTP POST requests from the embedded app to the `curl` with Linux `system("/usr/bin/curl ... ")` API...